# "Square root" of a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

It is well-known that each square matrix has a (non necessarily unique) square root.

I am wondering if there are some known conditions that allow for taking the "square root" of a homeomorphism.

Comment: This is surely way too general to say much of anything interesting.  Are there some specific spaces you're interested in?

Comment: The matrix $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ hast no square root since $A^2=0$ for every $2\times2$ matrix $A$ with 0 as its only eigenvalue.

Comment: Presumably you mean a homeomorphism from a space to itself. (Otherwise, what would a square root even mean?)

Comment: @Travis, yes I mean a space to itself

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, Doing a brief search I can't seem to find any results in this vein - that's why I ask such a nonspecific question.  Really, I am hoping to answer the following: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331156/square-root-of-a-holomorphic-automorphism

Comment: It's not clear exactly what class of maps you're considering in the linked question. (All homeomorphisms of $\Bbb C^n$?)

Comment: Anyway, (as Eric pointed out) this question is broad, not least because general topological spaces can be pretty wild. But NB in many cases it is easy to generate obstructions by looking at the maps a given homeomorphism induces on, e.g., homotopy and homology groups. For example, if $f: X \to X$ is a homeomorphism, then the induced map of its self-composition $f \circ f$ is $(f \circ f)_* = f_* \circ f_*$. Thus, if $g$ is a homeomorphism (or, for that matter, a continuous map $X \to X$) then $g_*$ must be in the image of the "squaring" operation on the appropriate space.

Comment: For relatively concreteness: If $M$ is a connected, oriented (toplogical) manifold, say, of dimension $n$, and $f: M \to M$ is a continuous map, then $H_n(M)\cong\Bbb Z$, and if we denote by $[X]$ a generator of $H_n(M)$, $f_*([X]) = d[X]$ for some integer called the *degree* $\deg f$ of $f$. Then, $(f\circ f)_*([X])=d^2[X]$, so if $g : M \to M$ admits a square root, $\deg g$ must be a square in $\Bbb Z$. For example, if we take $\phi : S^1 \to S^1$ to be the homeomorphism $z \mapsto z^{-1}$, then $\deg \phi = -1$, so there is no continuous map $\psi: S^1 \to S^1$ such that $\psi^2 = \phi$.